# Doing a Cumulative Count if in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, count, cumulative-sum, rownum

Please see attached file for reference. Lets say I have a Table `CARRIER_RESPONSE`, with the following fields `Carrier`, `Shipment`, `Acceptance`, `Day`

I would like to get  a Cumulative Count of Acceptance per Day for each Carrier.

So far I have come to the code below:

```
SELECT Carrier
,Shipment
,Acceptance
,Day
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY Carrier
                        , Day
                        , Acceptance
                        ORDER BY Day
                    ) AS "Cumulative Count of Acceptance per Day"
FROM CARRIER_RESPONSE
```

This code gives me the correct running count for the Lines with Acceptance Response = A but on the lines with Acceptance Response = D I also want to show the running count of Acceptance Response = A.

Essentially on every line I want to indicate how many times today the Carrier has accepted a Shipment. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Amir

Carrier Response:

[image: Carrier Response]

Comment: where is the attachment? if it is sample data why not just paste it as a text table? please also provide the complete sql query, you only have a snippet showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it - using sum with analytics clause and windowing.

```
SELECT Carrier
,Shipment
,Acceptance
,Day
,sum(Case when Acceptance is not null then 1 else 0 end) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY Carrier
                        , Day
                        ORDER BY Day
                        ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row
                    ) AS "Cumulative Count of Acceptance per Day"
FROM CARRIER_RESPONSE
```

Comment: One question: Instead of current row in the Over Clause, how can I say last row? So essentially I want to get the count from first row to last row (not current row)

Comment: Also what does "ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row" do and what would happen if I dont have it?

Comment: That is a windowing clause. You could say "between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding". The 
 full documentation is here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Answer (score 0):

After re read it seems you need count for both A and D

```
 SELECT Carrier
        ,Shipment
        ,Acceptance
        ,Day
        ,sum(Case when Acceptance='A' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY Carrier                                
                                ORDER BY Day                                
                            ) AS "Cumulative Count of Acceptance per Day",
sum(Case when Acceptance='D' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY Carrier                                
                                ORDER BY Day                                
                            ) AS "Cumulative Count for Deny per Day"
        FROM CARRIER_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT Carrier, Shipment, Acceptance, Day,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Acceptance = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
           (PARTITION BY Carrier
            ORDER BY Day
           ) AS "Cumulative Count of Acceptance per Day"
FROM CARRIER_RESPONSE;
```

If `Acceptance` only takes on the values `'A'` and `NULL`, then you can shorten this to:

```
SELECT Carrier, Shipment, Acceptance, Day,
       COUNT(Acceptance) OVER
           (PARTITION BY Carrier
            ORDER BY Day
           ) AS "Cumulative Count of Acceptance per Day"
FROM CARRIER_RESPONSE;
```